# "Task 'compile' is ambiguous in root project" - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I try to run my project, clean it or build it I get a gradle error:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'compile' is ambiguous in root project 'FifiFun2'. Candidates are: 'compileDebugAidl', 'compileDebugAndroidTestAidl', 'compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugAndroidTestNdk', 'compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript', 'compileDebugAndroidTestSources', 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugNdk', 'compileDebugRenderscript', 'compileDebugSources', 'compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugUnitTestSources', 'compileLint', 'compileReleaseAidl', 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac', 'compileReleaseNdk', 'compileReleaseRenderscript', 'compileReleaseSources', 'compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileReleaseUnitTestSources'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I have tried running gradle tasks with the options above (stacktrace,info,debug) but nothing helpful came up.

gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

main gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user_pc.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

settings.gradle file:

```
include ':app'
```

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: can you add the main module gradle file ? and settings.gradle ?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the module settings (shortcut F4) ? and/or your files i asked on the above comment ?

Comment: @Kalem Posted, please take a look,.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29834581/665823 . In other words, try to invalidate caches and restart (File > Invalidate ..)

Comment: @Kalem still not working....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [project built failed: Task 'compileDebug' is ambiguous in root project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540773/project-built-failed-task-compiledebug-is-ambiguous-in-root-project)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your gradlew file is in the root of your project and you are trying to run an ambiguous task compile from the root of the project, in which the compiler does not know the actual task to run, this will lead to TaskSelectionException. You can run a single task, this [stackoverflow question will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837421/how-to-run-a-single-gradle-task-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

from your gradle file, then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following :

Can you build and run another project? (New one for instance).

Try defining a debug buildType and resync gradle then build.

Check if you have a good proyect structure or set it in gradle.build if you don't.

If non of thoses work am out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. The solution I found was

1. Install latest version of Cordova.
2. Install latest version of gradle. You can do this Manually. Remember to updated GRADLE_HOME and PATH in System variables
3. Remove and reinstall android in your project. Remember to back up items such as Icons etc
4. Run `cordova build android --prod --release`. This will generate an App bundle instead of an APK file. This command will also hopefully download the latest version of gradle for your project.

Hope that helps some poor soul somewhere who is at their wits end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean the project(Top level menu `Build` --> `Clean Project`) first and then run the command again.